# ValidationError in Django Rest Framework JWT does not use custom exception handler

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using Django Rest Framework 3.2.3 (DRF) and Django Rest Framework JWT 1.7.2 (DRF-JWT, https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) to create Login tokens.

I need to change the Status Code for invalid credentials when issuing a JWT from 400 to 202 (FYI: my client can't read the body of non-200 responses). I use a custom exception handler as described by Django Rest Framework to achieve it: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

**restapi/custom_exception.py**

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework import status

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    print ('Exception raised: ' + str(response.status_code))

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None:
        if response.status_code != status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN:
            response.status_code = status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED

    return response
```

And in the config:

```
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'restapi.custom_exception.custom_exception_handler',
```

The DRF-JWT should raise ValidationError, when invalid credentials are used. I still get a 400 Bad Request response code, when posting invalid credentials to JWT token-auth interface.

With every other DRF interface I am getting the 202 status code as expected.

**How can I get DRF-JWT to use the custom exception handler for their ValidationErrors?**

Comment: If `raise ValidationError(msg)` is used in a view, the custom exception handler exceutes. If `raise ValidationError(msg)` is used within a serializer, the custom exception handler is **not** used. Is there a way to somehow extend DRF-JWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why we are not able to use custom exception handler here?**

This is happening because `raise_exception` flag has not been passed to the `JSONWebTokenSerializer` when calling `.is_valid()` on it.  ( `JSONWebTokenSerializer` is the serializer class used to validate a username and password.)

**DRF-JWT source code for `post()` method:**

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(
        data=get_request_data(request)
    )

    if serializer.is_valid(): # 'raise_exception' flag has not been passed here
        user = serializer.object.get('user') or request.user
        token = serializer.object.get('token')
        response_data = jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user, request)

        return Response(response_data)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now, we can see that `raise_exception` flag has not been passed to `is_valid()`. When this happens, `ValidationError` is not raised thereby resulting in non-execution of your `custom_exception_handler` code.

As per the DRF section on [Raising an exception on invalid data:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

> The `.is_valid()` method takes an optional **`raise_exception` flag that
>   will cause it to raise a [`serializers.ValidationError`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) exception** if
>   there are validation errors.
>
> These exceptions are automatically dealt with by the default exception
>   handler that REST framework provides, and will return HTTP 400 Bad
>   Request responses by default.

**SOLUTION:**

If you pass the `raise_exception` flag as `True` when calling the `.is_valid()` function, the code for `custom_exception_handler` will be executed.

You will need to create a `CustomObtainJSONWebToken` view which will inherit from the default `ObtainJSONWebToken` view. In this, we will override the `.post()` method to pass the `raise_exception` flag. Then will specify this view in our urls.

**my_app/views.py**

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import ObtainJSONWebToken

class CustomObtainJSONWebToken(ObtainJSONWebToken):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=get_request_data(request)
        )

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # pass the 'raise_exception' flag
        user = serializer.object.get('user') or request.user
        token = serializer.object.get('token')
        response_data = jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user, request)
        return Response(response_data)
```

**urls.py**

```
# use this view to obtain token
url(r'^api-token-auth/', CustomObtainJSONWebToken.as_view())
```

Comment: I find this sentence in the docs misleading, I was under the impression, that only if I modify the response directly with HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, the Exception handler is not used. 

Anyway, how can I use the exception handler for 400 errors in DRF-JWT?

Comment: I don't even think, this is appropriate. If I raise a ValidationError in a custom view `raise ValidationError('Invalid data.')` I still get the expected 202 status code. Though if the ValidationError is raised within JWT (https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py#L66-L67), it does not return a 202.

Comment: It was happening because of `raise_exception` flag not being passed to the `JSONWebTokenSerializer` when calling `.is_valid()` on it. If we pass this argument, then the custom exception handler will be used. Updated the ans.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm. I just had to add `from rest_framework_jwt.compat import get_request_data` and 
`from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings` which are used in `post()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe a cleaner way to do it that doesn't involve overriding the post method is

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework_jwt import serializers as jwt_serializers

class JSONWebTokenSerializer(jwt_serializers.JSONWebTokenSerializer):
    """
    Override rest_framework_jwt's ObtainJSONWebToken serializer to 
    force it to raise ValidationError exception if validation fails.
    """
    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=None):
        """
        If raise_exception is unset, set it to True by default
        """
        return super().is_valid(
            raise_exception=raise_exception if raise_exception is not 
None else True)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_jwt import views as jwt_views
from .serializers import JSONWebTokenSerializer

class ObtainJSONWebToken(jwt_views.ObtainJSONWebToken):
    """
    Override the default JWT ObtainJSONWebToken view to use the custom serializer
    """
    serializer_class = JSONWebTokenSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ObtainJSONWebToken

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', ObtainJSONWebToken.as_view(), name='jwt-create'),
]
```